# How can I run a interactive web app in R using Shiny App on GoDaddy hosted Website?

Tags: r, web-hosting, shiny

I'm not sure if I'm saying this correctly so please feel free to edit the post were need but now that I've created an R Script I know well, I'm learning how to build an interactive web app in R using shiny with the intention of running it on a particular webpage of my website (example.com/shiny-app).

I'm using MotoCMS so I think the only way I could accomplish thus is via the embedd feature. My website is hosted on Godaddy.

**With all that being said, is it possible to run a interactive web app in R using Shiny App on GoDaddy hosted MotoCMS Website?**

**Is there an online tutorial or could someone answer with the step by step process regarding how to run a interactive web app in R using Shiny App on GoDaddy specifically?**

**If I created a dedicated domain so that I wouldn't have to deal with my CMS but the hosting would still go through GoDaddy, could someone answer with the step by step process regarding how to run a interactive web app in R using Shiny App?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host your Shiny web app on http://shinyapps.io, then embed the link as a page in your MotoCMS website.

Comment: What if I created a dedicated domain so that I wouldn't have to deal with my CMS but the hosting would still go through GoDaddy?

Comment: The simplest way will be to [setup a custom domain with ShinyApps](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/custom-domains.html), or you can setup up an html page in your custom domain hosted on GoDaddy to redirect on-load to the app on shinyapps.io.